# Java to load URL in Firefox with an API or Callback?

Tags: java, firefox

I am trying to automate the loading of a webpage in Java. I am trying with Firefox although I guess the browser doesnt HAVE to be FF... My question is, are there any api where I call to load a url in Firefox and get a callback or something telling my program that the page is loaded?

Ive tried Selenium successfully but it takes too long for my liking so I would now like to load directly from a Java class.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            String path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
            Process process = runtime.exec(path + " " + "http://www.cnn.com");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
```

--OR--

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://cnn.com"));
```

I know the Java works in these 2 examples but again- no callback telling me the page is loaded. I use CentOS or Win7 so if there is a more compatible option Ill conform to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Will `process.waitFor()` do the trick?

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it doesnt take the webpage itself into account only the call to the browser. Thank you though for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The best you're likely to get is knowing the browser launched. I would suggest using the Desktop API as shown in your example.

Consider the failure modes of your approach. What if the network is unavailable? Do you want your code to wait until the page times out? What if the page loads *veeeery slowly?* What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?